# Axios cancel token doesn't work in live search react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm making a live search react application where you type search term in input and you get results (json) and I tried using axios cancel token, but it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why that is.

```
class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            results: {},
            isLoading: false,
            message: ''
        }
        this.cancelPrevRequest = '';
    }

    fetchSearchResults = (query) => {
        const jsonUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?q=${query}`;

        if(this.cancelPrevRequest) {
            this.cancelPrevRequest.cancel();
        }

        this.cancelPrevRequest = axios.CancelToken.source();

        axios.get(jsonUrl, { cancelPrevRequest: this.cancelPrevRequest.token })
        .then(res => {
            const resNotFoundMsg = !res.data.length ? "Sorry, we couldn't find anything" : '';
            this.setState({
                results: res.data,
                message: resNotFoundMsg,
                isLoading: false
            })
        })
        .catch(er => {
            if(axios.isCancel(er) || er) {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    message: "Error"
                })
            }
        })
    };

    handleOnInputChange = (ev) => {
        const query = ev.target.value;
        this.setState({ query: query, isLoading: true, message: '' }, () => {
            this.fetchSearchResults(query);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally with this kind of approach when calling an API `"onChange"` I personally tend to use `debounce` since I find it simpler.

As far as why your cancellation is not working, you should pass the `cancelToken` instead of `cancelPrevRequest`.

Make sure to read more on request [cancellation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation).